# Saving and getting image url in internal storage

Tags: android, image, url, save, internal-storage

I am working on an Android application in which I am getting image url from the server. Now I have to do save that image url and image file in my local storage, because for the first time if I want to check if the same url is available in my internal storage then it will get that image file from my local storage, if not then it will first save that image url reference and image file in my internal storage.

My code is given below. I wish to save image url and image file in my internal storage and according to the above conditions.

```
new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewProfile))
.execute(imageURL);

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }    
    }
```

Comment: Compare newly given url with existing.if url is exist don't fetch it again from network.use sqlite/file/shared preferences/ to save the url.

Comment: @AnoopM thanks for your reply. Can you please provide some code snippet here according to the above code. It will help me in this

Comment: You can store url in table and check your condition whatever

Comment: This is a library that allow download images and cache them in disk. Maybe it could be usefull. https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: Use the google's example. http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html just clik on download the sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for saving image once and reusing it many times this may help you [Google Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html#request-image) Library. [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) which is widely used after Volley.

**EDIT :**
Now there are bunch of libaries which are so popular.

1. [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)
2. [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)
3. [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco)

Choose according to your requirement.Here is [comparison](https://medium.com/@multidots/glide-vs-picasso-930eed42b81d).

Answer (score -1):

You can store url in table and check your condition whatever
download file from server and store it in external/internal storage.